# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet.connect(int, int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Am trying to set constraintSet but getting this error, what could be the source of the error.

I tried this
constraintSet.connect(R.id.label_value, ConstraintSet.END,R.id.label_description,ConstraintSet.END,0);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.label_value,ConstraintSet.START,R.id.label_description,ConstraintSet.START,0);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.label_value,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.label_amount,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);

But got this
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet.connect(int, int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: This error defines that your constraintSet is null

Comment: Check whether you imported correct class: import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.